# How to either tell IntelliJ not to check for node_modules either map docker path for indexing

Tags: macos, docker, intellij-idea

So I'm running an environnement where I build my node_modules into a Docker container and for performances on mac I keep them into my volume.

However it does not fit well with my IDE which is IntelliJ since he cannot detect my node_modules

So my question(s) are the following.

Is there a way to tell IntelliJ not to check if node_modules are there.

Or if its not working

Is there a way to tell IntelliJ to connect to docker container for indexing ?

Comment: You should share the volume of the docker app to your mac then.

Comment: @MathieuLescaudron well this is specifically what I want to avoid

Answer (score 1):

You can set `NODE_PATH` environment variable pointing to your `node_modules` location
in **Node.js** run configuration template: **Run | Edit Configurations...**, expand **Templates** node, select **Node.js** configuration, specify `NODE_PATH` in **Environment variables** field

Please see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-19476#focus=streamItem-27-2819977.0-0